# Ionic framework without Hash or History

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionicframework for my first android application my problem is my application has many tabs and inner pages and user can go through them but when user try to close application the back history pages are repeated on mobile back Navigation button(not the one in the UI header) just like normal browser of android or chrome.

What I want when it's on main page and user press Mobile Back button he should be out of application and don't go through all the tabs which he has viewed previously, as it make sense.

I've tried this but nothing works.

```
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableAnimate: true,
                disableBack: true
            });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $window.navigator.app.exitApp();
,101);
```

The code above registers a back-button action with priority 101 and closes the app on back-button if there's no modal / popup / side menu open. You might want to check something like `if ($state.current.name !== YOUR_HOME_STATE_NAME) {`.

See also: Documentation of [$ionicPlatform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/#registerBackButtonAction)

**EDIT:**
Since you still want to navigate backwards, you can use the [*$ionicHistory*](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)-Service with it's `goBack()`method.